# How to call Fastlane action or lane inside the shell script

Tags: shell, sh, fastlane

My question is very simple, how can I call some Fastlane actions directly from shell scripts? I want to do something like below, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Going to the directory that has the `fastlane` folder

Here Client directory have `fastlane` folder

```
cd $path/Client

// lane command:
fastlaneCommand="fastlane cs_expri"

// Run lane action
$fastlaneCommand
```